# How to create date intervals in Fullcalendar?

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I'm creating a fire department shift calendar with fullcalendar and I need to change the CSS of certain dates at intervals that do not correlate to days of the week.

A shift works three 24 hour shifts in a nine day period.  Each shift day is a certain color on the calendar.  See example...

[Shift Calendar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vYvA.jpg)

I know how to change the CSS of a date cell and repeat it by days of the week...

```
events: [{
            title:"Shift One",
            id: "one",
            allDay: true,
            rendering: 'background',
            color: 'blue',
            dow: [1,4]   // Repeat monday and thursday
            }]
```

But could I create a pattern of days 1,3,5 and repeat the pattern at day 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this appears to work https://jsfiddle.net/wavzxkjw/

The pattern starting on 2017-01-01 for shift day colors repeats every 18 days, so we use that to calcuate the color for the day from there.

**This first code block doesn't work going into the past (pre 2017-01-01)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
      $(cell).css('background-color', shiftDay(date));
    }
  });

  function shiftDay(date) {
    var pattern = [
      'red', 'goldenrod', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'black', 'goldenrod', 'black',
      'red', 'black', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'black',
      'goldenrod', 'black', 'red', 'black'
    ];
    var index = Math.abs(moment('2017-01-01').diff(date, 'days')) % pattern.length;
    return pattern[index];
  }
});
```

**Here it is cleaned up a bit and commented, supports past and future calculations, function name changed to be more representative of what it does https://jsfiddle.net/wavzxkjw/2/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
      $(cell).css('background-color', shiftColor(date));
    }
  });

  function shiftColor(date) {
    var pstart = '2017-01-01'; // pattern start date
    var pattern = [
      'red', 'goldenrod', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'black', 'goldenrod', 'black',
      'red', 'black', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'red', 'goldenrod', 'black',
      'goldenrod', 'black', 'red', 'black'
    ];
    var plen = pattern.length; // how many parts to the pattern
    // how many days from start of pattern are we
    var days = Math.abs(moment('2017-01-01').diff(date, 'days')) % plen;
    var index = 0; // pattern index
    if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') < pstart) {
      index = (plen - (days % plen)) % plen;
    } else {
      index = days % plen;
    }
    return pattern[index];
  }
});
```

Comment: You're a genius!  Thanks so much.  I was off in spaghetti code land and still couldn't solve this.